# How to iterate through the files in a zip folder without extracting them?

Tags: python, zip

I have a large dataset in zip format and I cannot unzip it directly because I have nowhere near to the amount of space needed on my machine.  I am trying to write a program that will iterate through the files inside the zip file and delete them as it copies it to another folder.  Sadly, `os.listdir` is of no help and I am wondering if there is a module in `zipfile` that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that provides the Linux/MacOs command for viewing the contents of a zip file without extracting: [Read contents without unzipping](https://superuser.com/questions/462788/read-the-contents-of-a-zipped-file-without-extraction)

You can use os.system (which basically executes terminal commands thru a python script) to get the contents of the zip. The link provides `unzip -l archive.zip` to list the files without unzipping. You can also use `unzip -c archive.zip` to get the contents of the files.

This will list the files without unzipping in the terminal

```
import os
os.system(unzip -l archive.zip)
```

If you want to get the names of files in a list for the python script to use, try this:

```
# import this module (available with vanilla python install)
import subprocess

# calls command and pipes results
process = subprocess.Popen(['unzip -c archive.zip'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# unpacks the results into a list
files = process.communicate()[0]
files = files.decode()
files = files.split("\n")
```

This uses the subprocess modules and Popen function to run a command via terminal and pipe the return for python to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zipfile.Path("your_zip.zip").iterdir()` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.Path.iterdir

```
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile
def test_iter_zip(tmp_path):
    dummy_files = ["1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt"]
    [Path(f"{tmp_path}{dummy_file}").touch() for dummy_file in dummy_files]
    with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{tmp_path}_zip.zip", "w") as archive:
        for dummy_file in dummy_files:
            archive.write(f"{tmp_path}{dummy_file}", dummy_file)

    # Now that the zip is created. There is how you can use the iterdir() to iterate the zip's file.
    zip_files = [file.name for file in zipfile.Path(f"{tmp_path}_zip.zip").iterdir()]
    for dummy_file in dummy_files:
        assert dummy_file in zip_files
```